# Clojure: Recur anonymous function with different arity

Tags: clojure, arity

Similar to [Clojure recur with multi-arity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546574/clojure-recur-with-multi-arity) I'd like recur with a different arity. But in my case, I define the function via a let, as I want to use another value from the let (`file-list`) without passing it:

```
(let [file-list (drive/list-files! google-drive-credentials google-drive-folder-id)
      download-file (fn
                      ([name]
                       (download-file ; <-- attempt to recur
                         name
                         (fn []
                           (throw
                             (ex-info
                               (str name " not found on Google Drive"))))))
                      ([name not-found-fn]
                       (if-let [file (->> file-list
                                          (filter #(= (:original-filename %)
                                                      name))
                                          first)]
                         (drive/download-file! google-drive-credentials file)
                         (not-found-fn))))]
  ;; #
  )
```

I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: download-file in this context`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a local name to the `fn`:

```
(let [download-file (fn download-file
                      ([name] (download-file name (fn ...))))
```

you could also use [`letfn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/letfn):

```
(letfn [(download-file
          ([name] (download-file name (fn ...)))
          ([name not-found-fn] ...)])
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to make more readable exception error messages, I often append `-fn` to the inner function name, like so:

```
(let [download-file (fn download-file-fn [name] ...) ]
   <use download-file> ...)
```